# Twilio.API on NuGet is out of date

Tags: twilio

The Twilio.API package has a dependency of RestSharp, but the latest version of RestSharp that is downloaded is 104.2 and the Twilio.API is referencing 104.1.  I've worked around this by manually installing the right version of RestSharp using the Package Manager Nuget command line.  Please can you update your Twilio.API NuGet Package with a version that references the correct release of RestSharp.

Thanks,
Ian.

EDIT - More details on my setup:

I have a class library project where I installed the Twilio.Api NuGet Package and created a class with some methods that use the TwilioClient functionality.  I reference this class library project in another project (same solution) and call into those classes that use Twilio features, it was at this point I get an exception saying:

Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp, Version=104.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.

I've tried installing the Twilio.Api package into a new console application project and it works flawlessly.  So, it might be something todo with my Solution configuration.

Comment: Twilio Developer Evangelist here, thanks for letting us know - we'll take a look and make sure everything is updated. Shoot me an email at wawra at twilio, as we'd love to send you a t-shirt for spotting this!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't Twilio's bug tracker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here (and maintainer of the .NET helper lib).

Can you shoot me an email: devin [at] twilio [dot] com.

I tried spinning up a new project this morning and using the NuGet package and was unable to reproduce the assembly not found error, which is what I'd expect to see.  I'd love to know more about your project specifics in order to try to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I've updated the Question with some more details on how I was using the NuGet Twilio.Api.

Comment: Out of interest, did your new project download RestSharp 104.2 and does Twilio.Api code reference that RestSharp 104.1 specifically ?

Comment: Just to close the loop in this.  I pushed an new nuget package a couple of days ago that includes an update of the assembly references.  This should fix the version issue.

Comment: Yup.  Looks like we had a bad push to nuget.  I just pushed out a new version which should actually fix the issue.

Comment: I am getting this error today, though the version numbers have changed.  NuGet is pulling RestSharp 104.4, but the Twilio.Api is referencing RestSharp 104.3.

Comment: Tim: Can you shoot me an email please (its in my answer above).  I've been trying to hunt down this issue for a while but I've never been able to reproduce it myself.

Comment: @Devin Rader - I am still seeing this issue today. How do I fix this?

Comment: @DevinRader Got this issue as well... solved. See my answer :)

Comment: This is still not fixed as of 4/28/16. Oliver's solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue with Twilio 3.4.1 package.

Having a closer look at Twilio.Api dll with DotPeek gives the following:

[image: assemblies]

I opened RestSharp by double clicking the dependency... and here is the thing: It seems that nuget has installed RestSharp 104.5, while Twilio is expecting 104.4 !

This must be a misconfiguration of Twilio nupkg, I guess :/

To address the issue within visual studio package manager (View->other windows->package manager console and then select the right project) type:

```
Uninstall-Package RestSharp -Force
Install-Package RestSharp -Version 104.4.0
```

(replace 104.4.0 with the version you've got in the exception message)

Comment: Yup.  RestSharp just posted a new version and everytime they do it seems to break the Twilio library for some.  I've never been able to figure out why or reproduce it reliably.  I'm working on getting a new version with an updated reference pushed out, but they also broke the version of SL and Windows Phone that they support so I have to upgrade all of that stuff as well.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you make the reference/dependency non version specific ?

Comment: It already is.  In all of the projects that take a dependency on RestSharp, the "Specific Version" property of that reference is set to 'false' and have been for some time.  This is whats confounding me.

Comment: Thanks Oliver .. I had the same situation with the Twilio NuGet package. Looks like Twilio has still not fixed their NuGet package. I followed your steps (but changed the RestSharp version to 105.2.3.0) 
1)  `Uninstall-Package RestSharp -Force` 
 2)  `Install-Package RestSharp -Version 105.2.3.0`. Now it is working fine.